# Finding placeholders and put then in an array

Tags: php, arrays, placeholder

In my string I have place holders like: ##NEWSLETTER## , ##FOOTER# ##GOOGLEANALYTICS## etc.

Each of those placeholders is delimited by: ##

I want to find each of thos placeholders and put them in an array.

The tricky part is that what's inside the ## delimiters can be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$s = "asdff ##HI## asdsad ##TEST## asdsadsadad";

preg_match_all("~##([^#]+)##~", $s, $result);

var_dump($result[1]);
```

prints:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "HI"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "TEST"
}
```

Comment: Please note, that if you want to be able to match a single '#' within a placeholder (eg. "##TE#ST##"), then you should change the regexp to
##([^#]|#[^#])+##

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preg_match_all()`:

```
$str = '##NEWSLETTER## , some more text ##FOOTER## test 123 ##GOOGLEANALYTICS## aaa';
preg_match_all('/##([^#]+?)##/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will have all your placeholders