# Finding placeholders and put then in an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have following text.

```
My name is ++name++. My age is ++age++. Name of my city is ++city++ and so on.
```

So I want to find out all the instances wrap withing ++ and push them into array with jQuery.

Comment: And then where are you stuck? You have to provide in question any of your attempt

Comment: You haven't really asked a *question* here... It looks more like the specifications of a task you have been given. Where exactly do you need assistance with this?

Comment: not able to catch the instances which are wrap by ++.

Comment: @HarshalSawant - can you please share with us the code you are using now?

Comment: I came across 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388083/finding-placeholders-and-put-then-in-an-array 
but want to achieve same with jquery.

Comment: jQuery can handle DOM nodes, this appears to be a Regex question. jQuery has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"My name is ++name++. My age is ++age++. Name of my city is ++city++ and so on."
    .match(/\+\+.*?\+\+/g)
    .map(function(s){
        return s.slice(2, -2);
    })
```

Comment: Oh sorry for late reply. I am new here. :)